# How to delete JSON keys from an array with PHP?

Tags: php, json

I have the following array, and I want to be able to delete all the "phonenumber" keys and of course its value from the JSON objects. Only the keys "phonenumber" an not the whole object. How can I do that?

```
[
    {
        "role": "admin",
        "id": "59df4ef2d8d39",
        "email": "a@a.dk",
        "name": "A",
        "lastname": "A",
        "password": "1",
        "image": "img_webshop\/userimage-59dfb91515810.png"
    },
    {
        "role": "user",
        "id": "59df4f1b070e6",
        "phonenumber": "12345678",
        "name": "B",
        "lastname": "B",
        "password": "2",
        "image": "img_webshop\/userimage-59e37de69475b.png"
    },
    {
        "role": "user",
        "id": "59dfc0cb07985",
        "email": "c@c.dk",
        "name": "C",
        "lastname": "C",
        "password": "3",
        "image": "img_webshop\/userimage-59dfc0cb06c5f.png"
    },
    {
        "role": "user",
        "id": "59dfc22f26f78",
        "phonenumber": "87654321",
        "name": "D",
        "lastname": "D",
        "password": "4",
        "image": "img_webshop\/userimage-59dfc22f2638d.png"
    },
    {
        "role": "user",
        "id": "59dfc460b261e",
        "email": "e@e.dk",
        "name": "E",
        "lastname": "E",
        "password": "5",
        "image": "img_webshop\/userimage-59dfc460af866.png"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
// make array
$array = json_decode($your_json_string, true);

// loop through array
foreach($array as $key => $item){
       // unset them
       unset($array[$key]["phonenumber"]);
}

// make json again
$json_string_modified = json_encode($array);
```

**OR using reference**

```
// make array
$array = json_decode($your_json_string, true);

// loop through array using reference
foreach($array as &$item){

      // unset specific key
      unset($item["phonenumber"]);

}

// unset reference
unset($item);

// make json again
// you may remove JSON_PRETTY_PRINT flag, I kept it just to see o/p
$json_string_modified = json_encode($array,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Comment: I don't think you need the isset test. If it's not there, unset doesn't error.

Answer (score 1):

```
$jsonArray=json_decode($data);
//Remove unvanted props
foreach ($jsonArray as $key=>$row) {

   foreach ($row as $prop=>$field) {
       if ($prop != 'phonenumber')
           $newArray[$key][$prop] = $field;
       }

}

 $jsonArray=json_encode($newArray);
```

Comment: This uses potentially lots of memory to make a clone array and is slower than @3161993

Comment: yeah you are right but some php versions not remove object property .if this property protected then you cant make any changes

Comment: You're dealing with *arrays* here, not objects.